# Create using save() is causing database duplicates in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have very similar code that is functioning without a hitch elsewhere in my Laravel app, but for some reason the below code is creating two $paypal_object database entries that are identical except for the payment_id field:

**DonateController.php**

```
public function mimic()
{
    try {
        //This block is the addOrder function from the pizza tutorial
        $paypal_object = new Paypal();
        //The user who is making the payment
        $paypal_object->user()->associate(Auth::user());
        $paypal_object->amount = 50.00;
        $paypal_object->description = "new subscription";
        $paypal_object->state = $payment->getState();
        $paypal_object->payment_id = $payment->getId();
        $paypal_object->save();
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $message = $ex->getMessage();
        $messageType = "error";
    }
    exit;
}
```

**Database Results (with test data)**
[image]

I've condensed the above code from my controller a little.  If you'd like to see more of my code, let me know and I'd be happy to provide it.  My theory right now is that for some reason my mimic() method is getting run twice, but I'm not sure how to test to see if that's true beyond including this in the above code, but it's not giving me any results this time:

```
    echo '<script>console.log(' . json_encode("Testing to see how many times this message appears.") . ');</script>';
```

Even if it is running twice, I'm not sure how that's happening or where to check.  I'm guessing it could well be another problem entirely, but I don't know what.

Right now, I'm accessing this method by pinging its route:

```
Route::get('/paypal/mimic', 'DonateController@mimic');
```

but for every 1 ping I make, I get 2 database entries as shown in the above image.

**Paypal model:**

```
class Paypal extends Eloquent
{
    /**
     * Get the user that made the paypal payment.
     */
    public function user()
    {
        # Defines an inverse one-to-many relationship
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

**User model:**

```
public function paypal(){
        # User has many paypal payments - although just one subscription
        # Defines a one-to-many relationship
        return $this->hasMany('Paypal');
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Where are you calling this method from? It might be bit tough to guess without looking at the caller?

Comment: @AchinthaGunasekara Right now, I'm just manually pinging its route:  Route::get('/paypal/mimic', 'DonateController@mimic');

Comment: I assume that problem is with associate method. Let me ask some questions, what's the relation between **Paypal** model and **User** model?

Comment: @MustafaEhsan Thanks for contributing.  I have a 1-to-many relationship set up.  I'll add the code above.  Strangely enough, the problem seems to go away when the user is not already logged in.

Comment: Use the Log facade like this Log::info("mimic function called") in your mimic function, then check storage\logs and see how many messages are stored.

Comment: @ShaunUK Thanks for the tip.  I'll check it out after the weekend.

Comment: have you gotten any luck?